# How to preview a image before upload using JavaScript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I just need to display the image chosen (Browse) by the user before the upload. For this purpose i am using this code:

**JS**

```
function setImage(file) {
    if(document.all)
        document.getElementById('prevImage').src = file.value;
    else
        document.getElementById('prevImage').src = file.files.item(0).getAsDataURL();
    if(document.getElementById('prevImage').src.length > 0) 
        document.getElementById('prevImage').style.display = 'block';
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img id="prevImage"  src=""  alt="" width="313" height="315" />
<input name="photo1" id="photo1" type="file" onchange="setImage(this);"  value="" class="input" size="17"/>
```

This code working fine in Safari, Firefox 3,4,5 but doesn't work in Google Chrome 12 or higher and IE 8, 9.

So please tell me any solution regarding this issues?

I already tried other solution given on this website but they are also not working in all major browsers.

if you have a solution for this code or a completely new code then please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a complete solution from another [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126464/php-jquery-upload-image-and-preview-display-instantly), [here](http://www.zurb.com/playground/ajax_upload) is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [FileReader](http://bgrins.github.io/filereader.js/) which is a standard Web API now.